# Converting string array into binary string

Tags: c#

I have a string array with numeric elements:

```
string[] numbers = {"2","3","10","9","4"};
```

I would like to convert each string to a 16-bit binary equivalent and concatenate, such that resulting string must look like this:

```
00000000000000100000000000000011000000000000101000000000000010010000000000000100
```

Do I have to convert string array to int array and apply a /2 function or is there any other efficient way to achieve that? Also, how do I get 16bit results?

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = string.Join("", numbers.Select(n => Convert.ToString(Int16.Parse(n), 2).PadLeft(16, '0')));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, it is giving me following error........... Suppression State Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string'

Comment: Oops, forgot the string.Join. Better now.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Proggram
{
    internal class Program
    {


        internal static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            string[] numbers = { "2", "3", "10", "9", "4" };
            foreach (var number in numbers)
            {
                sb.Append(NumbertoStrToBinaryStr(number));
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            return 0;
        }


        private static string NumbertoStrToBinaryStr(string numberstr)
        {
            var result = new StringBuilder();
            if (!uint.TryParse(numberstr, out var n)) return result.ToString();

            const int start =  32 - 1;
            for (var mask = 1u << start; mask != 0; mask >>= 1)
            {
                var set = (mask & n) == mask;
                result.Append( set ? '1' : '0');
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use for loop to access each element like this code...

```
string binary_number ="";
string[] numbers = { "2", "3", "10", "9", "4" };
for (int i = 0;i < numbers.Length;i++) {
  binary_number += Convert.ToString(Int16.Parse(numbers[i]), 2).PadLeft(16, '0')));
}
```